# Remove TextView context Card.io scan activity

Tags: android, card.io

There is TextView Context into rectangle "Hold card here. It will scan automatically." when using CardIOActivity.

How can I remove this TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff from card.io here.  Sorry, at the moment there's no way to remove this text.

Comment: What about the background of the rectangle? There is a gradient background. Can I change it with transparent color ?

Comment: I assume you're talking about the rectangle corners, which are meant as guides for where to place the card.  While you can provide your own color, transparency is removed so that the rectangle is always visible.

Comment: Nope, I meant in the rectangle. Gradient color with black and white in the rectangle. How can I remove this color? This gradient not allow to show credit card.

Comment: Have you reviewed the solution in the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues/21)?  That issue is aimed at hardware acceleration, which could be your issue too.

Comment: Exactly!! This solution solved gradient problem. Thx!!